# Select and Delete Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

```
With Sheet(name)

    .ListObjects(Table_name).ShowTotals = False

    .ListObjects(Table_name).Range.AutoFilter _
      Field:=8, Criteria1:=ListBox1.Value, _
      Operator:=xlFilterValues

       .ListObjects(Table_name).DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete

    .ListObjects(Table_name).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    .ListObjects(Table_name).ShowTotals = True

  End With
```

the problem is in

`.ListObjects("Table13").DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete`

It does not delete the rows and I do not understand why...

Comment: What’s the problem. Please provide a more detailed explanation and include a screenshot or a sample of the data you’re working with

Answer (score 0):

Tables don't work the same way as regular ranges.  Even if you go into Excel, click into the table and try to do Alt-E-D (delete).  Normally it would give you the option to shift cells up, shift cells left, delete entire row or delete entire column, but if you do this from a table it won't do anything.

I'm speculating a little, but I suspect this has something to do with your unexpected behavior.

Instead, if you just want to delete the rows, delete the table rows (ListRows) instead:

```
.ListObjects(Table_name).ListRows(row_number).Delete
```

Or if you want to delete them all (as it appears in your question):

```
For i = .ListObjects(Table_name).ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
  .ListObjects(Table_name).ListRows(i).Delete
Next i
```

If you don't do it backwards, I'm pretty sure it skips rows and then breaks.

Then there is always the scorched earth approach:

```
.ListObjects(Table_name).DataBodyRange.Delete
```

Unless you care about the contents in those same rows outside of your data table, these should work.

Answer (score 0):

For Deleting rows in a Auto Filtered table use have to use

```
 .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

The following example program works for me. Since your table is linked to List Box make appropriate adjustment for criteria.
[Table before delete]

[image: table before delete]Table after Delete

[image: table after delete]

```
 Sub DeleteRows()
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1") 'Change table as per your requirement
             If .Parent.FilterMode Then .Range.AutoFilter
             .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Margeret"    'Set criteria as per yr requirements
             .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
             .Range.AutoFilter
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```